# Long running statement not monitored by Oracle

Tags: oracle, monitoring

We are trying to find out why a (pretty complicated) statement has an extremely high variance in runtime. Sometimes it just takes "minutes" (around 40-50) and sometimes it does not finish even after 12 hours.

My usual approach to problems like that is to check if the statement is monitored and if it is, get the "real-time" execution of it using `dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor()` so I can pin-point the bottleneck in the execution.

However that specific statement is never monitored by Oracle. According to the Oracle manual a statement is monitored, if:

> By default, SQL monitoring is automatically started when a SQL statement either runs in parallel or has consumed at least 5 seconds of combined CPU and I/O time in a single execution

As this statement runs for substantially longer then 5 seconds **and** uses parallel execution it should be monitored.

We even added the hints `gather_plan_statistics` and `monitor` to the SQL to force monitoring of the statement, but still it's not monitored.

According to "My Oracle Support" (DocID: 1613163.1) monitoring is limited to statements with a plan with less then 300 lines. When I generate the plan, it has 282 lines (=highest line ID in the plan), so that should not prevent monitoring.

There is a hidden parameter (`"_sqlmon_max_planlines"`) that controls this, but this is a hosted database server and changing something like that is quite complicated.

#### So my question is:

Are there any other (maybe undocumented) restrictions on why Oracle would not monitor a statement?

---

This is an Oracle 11.2.0.3 Enterprise Edition (upgrade to 11.2.0.4 is scheduled, but that might take some time).

Comment: "Running" for > 5 seconds is not the same as consuming more than 5 seconds of CPU time. Check for blocking locks?

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ: good point, but no lock waits are visible for that statement in `v$active_session_history` (usually only `db file sequential read` waits - which is to be expected)

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ: plus: parallel queries should **always** be monitored according to the manual regardless of the CPU they use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement in question had multiple plans (13 to be precise) which for some reason were not returned by `dbms_xplan.display_cursor()`. The plan returned by that function was one with less then 300 lines, but other plans had more then 300 lines.

After the hosting partner increased the `"_sqlmon_max_planlines"` parameter to 500, the statement is now monitored.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the SQL_ID, you can also issue:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET EVENTS 'sql_monitor [sql: 5hc07qvt8v737] force=true';
```

to ensure monitoring takes place (for example, even for short running SQL statements)

Comment: and how do you then turn it off?

Comment: ALTER SYSTEM SET EVENTS 'sql_monitor [sql: 5hc07qvt8v737] off' or just 'ALTER SYSTEM SET EVENTS 'sql_monitor off'

Comment: SQL doesn't apper in Oracle monitor using this. What's wrong? What Oracle version does support this?

Comment: see here for potential causes https://tanelpoder.com/2013/10/07/why-doesnt-alter-system-set-events-set-the-events-or-tracing-immediately/